# Staircase Print Pattern using Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing

```
static void UsingArray(int n) {
    String[] arr = new String[n];
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (int c1 = 0; c < (n - c - 1); c++) {
            arr[c1] = " ";
            System.out.print(arr[c1]);
        }
        for (int c1 = (n - 1); c1 > (n - c - 2); c1--) {
            arr[c1] = "#";
            System.out.println(arr[c1]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I tried that and was expecting output like this:

```
//if n = 4
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

but it throws me this:

```
//n = 4
   #
#
#
#
```

Im wracking my brain to debug this but taking me so many hours right now (I tried all different methods including recursion, stringbuilder to solve this print pattern question, and array method is the only one I can't do it right now)

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Are you using an IDE to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `System.out.println(arr[c1]);` .It should be should be `System.out.print(arr[c1]);` because `println()` prints and extra `newline`. Also you don't need  `arr[c1]` you can just use `System.out.print(" ");` or `System.out.print("#");`

Modified code :-

```
static void UsingArray(int n) {
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (int c1 = 0; c1 < (n - c - 1); c1++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int c1 = c; c1 >= 0; c1--) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**Output :-**

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Comment: you have made mistake in this condition c1 < (n - c). With this condition to output will be added one space.  Right condition (n - c - 1)

Comment: @Maxim thanks for that notification. I have changed that .